# Sorting a file up to a character

Tags: bash, sorting

I am writing a bash script. I have a file like this

```
./1#1#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./11.txt#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/1#1#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/1#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/1.txt#1#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/1.txt#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/2.txt#1#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/2.txt#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./1#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./13#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./2.txt#1#5d74727d50368c4741d76989586d91de
./2.txt#2#5d74727d50368c4741d76989586d91de
```

I would like to sort this file, but in a specific way. Let's call characters up to the first `#` section one, between the two `#` characters section two. So for example, given a line like this:

```
./1#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Section one: ./1

Section two: 2

What I want to achive is sorting this file according to section one first and then according to section 2. So what is wrong with this example is the 9th line, it should be 2nd.

Is there an easy way to achieve this goal? I am unsure how to tackle this problem. Maybe I should somehow sort this file up to the first `#` and then again only according to the second section? Even if this is a good answer, not sure how to do it.

Expected result:

```
./1#1#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./1#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./11.txt#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/1#1#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/1#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/1.txt#1#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/1.txt#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/2.txt#1#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/2.txt#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./13#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./2.txt#1#5d74727d50368c4741d76989586d91de
./2.txt#2#5d74727d50368c4741d76989586d91de
```

Comment: post the final expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just want to sort by more than one key:

```
$ sort -t# -k1,1 -k2 file
./1#1#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./1#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./11.txt#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/1#1#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/1#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/1.txt#1#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/1.txt#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/2.txt#1#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./12/2.txt#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./13#2#d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./2.txt#1#5d74727d50368c4741d76989586d91de
./2.txt#2#5d74727d50368c4741d76989586d91de
```

`-k1,1` means sort by only the first field, *then* `-k2` means sort by the rest of the fields, starting from the second. `-t#` means that fields are separated by a `#`.